# How to get InetAddress with wildcard ip 0.0.0.0?

Tags: java, pmd

`InetAddress` doesn't provide any static method or constructor to get `InetAddress` with wildcard IP 0.0.0.0 . The only way is `InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0")`

But PMD gives `AvoidUsingHardCodedIP` if we pass hard coded IP. Is there any way to get `InetAddress` with wildcard IP but without hard coding the IP?

Comment: you could generate it if you have subnet mask bits.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov one of the method I am calling accepts InetAddress as an argument. Where I passed InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0") but PMD is showing AvoidUsingHardCodedIP error.

Comment: what is PMD? Can you post more code here?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov PMD is a source code analyzer. http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.1/rules/index.html#Basic

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know that this is a little bit old. But i was in the same situation:

```
InetAddress wildCard = new InetSocketAddress(0).getAddress();
```

does the trick. The main constructor

```
public InetSocketAddress(InetAddress addr, int port)
```

will be called with

```
InetAddress.anyLocalAddress()
```

The port is not needed so i picked 0.

Answer (score 1):

use `InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {0,0,0,0})` will work. but don't forget to check listen on `ipv4` or `ipv6`.